# Raspberry Pi SSH lag slowness

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I am experiencing issues with the Pi. When I try to work on the Pi through SSH I suddenly get lag. At the beginning it works fine, but intermittently the auto-complete or commands on the history take a long time to load and that affects the typing.

How can I find out what is doing this?

Comment: What are you doing when the lag happens? Have you tried running `top` or `htop` to see system ressources?

Comment: I have tried everything I can think of... resources where good and network too. If I open another terminal it connects fine and there's no lag for a while untill it's starts heppening, havent been able to find a petern but it affects tab autocomplete and anything else... my workaround for the time being it's to install and use tmux once in a tmux session all work nice and smooth...

Comment: I've found when that happens the sd card is about to fail! well, "about to" can be weeks, but I've had 2 (major) failures, and both times, ssh demonstrated the behaviour in your question leading up to the fail. My suggestion is to copy the sd card onto another card ASAP

Comment: Turn off or dev/null logging as well. It saves the life of SD cards.

Comment: Any advise on good quality SDs for the Pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading around I found that could be an issue with network, the SD card R/W speeds or even the SSH configuration itself, nothing that I tried of what I found around worked for me which was quite disappointing.

I don't know which the problem was exactly on my case.

I found a solution for me thanks to that several time my SSH session dropped an this is particularly painful If on the middle of running a command, so i decided to look for a way to keep session alive independently I found tmux. Which no only allowed me to keep session alive but it improved my ssh response, I read that mosh would do the same but I decided to go with tmux which work perfectly for me.

No idea why this is. I'm assuming it's because the way it's built maybe adding a bigger quicker buffer. But it work for me and it even help me when working from different PCs or coming back to a session, it's really good!!!